# Local labels in GNU assembler; gdb printing backtrace as though labels are functions

Tags: assembly, gdb, debug-symbols, gnu-assembler, backtrace

Two pieces of example code; first some C++ code calling into assembly:

```
/* test1.cc */
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" void blah();
extern "C" void stuff() {
  printf( "This is a test\n" );
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  blah();

  return 0;
}
```

... then the assembly:

```
.file "test2.s"
.text
.globl blah, stuff
.type blah,@function
.type stuff,@function
.align 16

blah:
  /* normal function preamble */
  pushl %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp

label1:
  call stuff

  leave
  retn
```

Built with:

```
as -g --32 test2.s -o test2.o
clang++ -m32 -g test1.cc -c
clang++ -m32 -g test*.o -o test
```

Run it under gdb, set a breakpoint on stuff(), then look at the backtrace:

```
gdb test
(gdb) break stuff
(gdb) run
(gdb) back
     #0  stuff () at test1.cc:5
---> #1  0x08048458 in label1 () at test2.s:12
---> #2  0xffffc998 in ?? ()
     #3  0x0804843e in main (argc=1, argv=0xffffca44) at test1.cc:9
```

After sifting through [*edit* an older copy of] the GNU assembler documentation, I tried labels prefixed with `L` & postfixed with `$` to see if it would prevent the labels from being exported, but it didn't work.

If I make the labels numeric the backtrace looks normal, but I'm not overly fond of the notion of using numeric labels.

Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Local labels should start with `.L` (`dot L`). For example, `.Llabel1` works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found an answer [in the GNU assembler manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html); quoting from that doc:

> A local symbol is any symbol beginning with certain local label prefixes. By default, the
>   local label prefix is ‘.L’ for ELF systems or ‘L’ for traditional a.out systems, but each target
>   may have its own set of local label prefixes.

Sure enough, as soon as I put `.L` on there, it worked.

`.L` labels don't appear as symbols in the object file.

Comment: I asked if there is any way to break on such local labels: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226798/how-to-make-local-labels-in-gnu-gas-elf-output-that-gdb-can-break-on-but-not-cou