# How to make local labels in GNU GAS ELF output that GDB can break on but not count as functions?

Tags: gdb, elf, gnu-assembler, dwarf

When writing assembly manually with GNU GAS, within a function, I want to set a label such that:

- GDB won't treat that label as the function name
- I can use `b mylabel` to break on the label

A similar question for `nasm` has been asked at: [Break at local label using GDB for NASM assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944547/break-at-local-label-using-gdb-for-nasm-assembly) but I wanted to make it more precise here that I want GNU GAS and ELF output.

E.g. if I defined a normal label `mylabel` as in:

main.S

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
    /* exit */
    mov $60, %rax
mylabel:
    mov $0, %rdi
    syscall
```

that does not satisfy me because when GDB reaches the `mov $0, %rdi`, `bt` shows `mylabel` as the function name, and I would like it to be `_start` instead. In particular, this can break backtraces because GDB can't find the stack frame: [How gdb reconstructs stacktrace for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349162/how-gdb-reconstructs-stacktrace-for-c)

However, if I replace `mylabel` with `.Lmylabel` as explained at: [Local labels in GNU assembler; gdb printing backtrace as though labels are functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065107/local-labels-in-gnu-assembler-gdb-printing-backtrace-as-though-labels-are-funct/26065570#26065570) then `_start` is the function name as desired, but `b .Lmylabel` fails. `nm` does not show the symbol at all either.

Does the ELF / DWARF formats support anything that could be used, and is there any way to expose that though GNU GAS?

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, GDB 8.2, GNU GAS 2.31.1.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this fits your needs, but you can do this (for a non-PIE binary, so link with `-no-pie`):

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
    /* exit */
    mov $60, %rax
.Lmylabel:
    mov $0, %rdi
    syscall
    .section .rodata
mylabel:
    .long .Lmylabel
```

Then, you can set a breakpoint using `break *mylabel` (note the `*`):

```
(gdb) break *mylabel
Breakpoint 2 at 0x401007: file t.S, line 7.
```

Since `mylabel` is more or less a function pointer, GDB does not know anything about it and will ignore it:

```
Breakpoint 1, _start () at t.S:5
5       mov $60, %rax
(gdb) si
7       mov $0, %rdi
```

With a linker script, it should be possible to put the `mylabel` symbol into a section which is not loaded, to reduce run-time overhead.

Comment: Hi Florian, I'll keep this tip in mind, but it is so hacky, I will likely just let my stack traces blow up :-) (my goal is just user friendliness of debugging).